# Table Row explode with the delimeters comparing it to the other and show it

Tags: php, html

Here is my code

```
<?php



$split_getCreatedfield = explode(",", "1,5,3");

$fieldsWithValue = explode("~","1->Sample 1~3->Sample 2~5->Sample 3~");

   for($c=0;$c<=count($split_getCreatedfield);$c++){

         for($b=0;$b<=count($fieldsWithValue)-2;$b++){

             $data = explode("->", $fieldsWithValue[$b]);

                 if($data[0]==$split_getCreatedfield[$c]){

                      echo "<td>"; 

                            echo $data[1];

                                 echo "</td>";

                  }
             }
        }
?>
```

I want the output like this using table

**Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3**

**Sample 1 | Sample 2 | Sample 3**

then if `$split_getCreatedfield` doesnt match to the `$data[0]`

i want the output like this

**Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3**

**Sample 1 |          | Sample 3**

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I want the output in the table... please try to resolve my code